# How do I select a value in R from an xml document?

Tags: r, xpath

I have an xml document of some health data, which is the default apple health db export format.  I have truncated that document here, but it is a valid xml document.  How do I select all "value" attributes that match another attribute?  e.g., how do I get a matrix or data frame for all `type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass"`?  Or all of my heights?

I have tried something like this, but it only return null values.

````
library(xml2)

xml <- read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HealthData locale="en_US">
 <ExportDate value="2021-10-29 20:24:26 -0700"/>
 <Me HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth="1975-05-18" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex="HKBiologicalSexMale" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType="HKBloodTypeNotSet" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierFitzpatrickSkinType="HKFitzpatrickSkinTypeNotSet" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierCardioFitnessMedicationsUse="None"/>
 <Record
         type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight"
         sourceName="Neil’s Apple Watch"
         sourceVersion="2.1"
         unit="ft"
         creationDate="2016-02-23 14:12:38 -0700"
         startDate="2016-02-23 14:12:38 -0700"
         endDate="2016-02-23 14:12:38 -0700"
         value="6.16667"/>
 <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight" sourceName="Neil’s Apple Watch" sourceVersion="2.2.1" unit="ft" creationDate="2016-08-17 08:00:37 -0700" startDate="2016-08-17 08:00:37 -0700" endDate="2016-08-17 08:00:37 -0700" value="6.16667"/>
 <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass" sourceName="Neil’s Apple Watch" sourceVersion="2.1" unit="lb" creationDate="2016-02-23 14:12:38 -0700" startDate="2016-02-23 14:12:38 -0700" endDate="2016-02-23 14:12:38 -0700" value="175"/>
 <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass" sourceName="Neil’s Apple Watch" sourceVersion="2.2.1" unit="lb" creationDate="2016-08-17 08:00:36 -0700" startDate="2016-08-17 08:00:36 -0700" endDate="2016-08-17 08:00:36 -0700" value="180"/>
 <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass"
         sourceName="Neils Apple Watch"
         sourceVersion="2.1"
         unit="lb"
         creationDate="2016-02-23 14:12:38 -0700"
         startDate="2016-02-23 14:12:38 -0700"
         endDate="2016-02-23 14:12:38 -0700"
         value="175"/>
</HealthData>')

listOfAllMyHeights <- xml_text(xml, "???")
listOfAllMyWeights <- xml_something("???") 


print(heights)```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
xml2::xml_find_all(xml, ".//Record") %>% 
  purrr::map(xml_attrs) %>%
  purrr::map_df(as.list)
  
#   type                             sourceName  sourceVersion unit  creationDate  startDate  endDate  value
#   <chr>                            <chr>       <chr>         <chr> <chr>         <chr>      <chr>    <chr>
# 1 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight   Neil’s App~ 2.1           ft    2016-02-23 1~ 2016-02-2~ 2016-02~ 6.16~
# 2 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight   Neil’s App~ 2.2.1         ft    2016-08-17 0~ 2016-08-1~ 2016-08~ 6.16~
# 3 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass Neil’s App~ 2.1           lb    2016-02-23 1~ 2016-02-2~ 2016-02~ 175  
# 4 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass Neil’s App~ 2.2.1         lb    2016-08-17 0~ 2016-08-1~ 2016-08~ 180  
# 5 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass Neils Appl~ 2.1           lb    2016-02-23 1~ 2016-02-2~ 2016-02~ 175
```